# Grab text from a search bar suggestion drop down list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, rpa

I'm practicing with robot framework on amazon website.

The test case I want to do is:
Click on search bar
Type on the search bar
Cycle through the suggestions given
And click on the one that matches what I want

However, any action I try related with this suggestion list I get the error message: Stale element reference: stale element not found.

Something as simple as this isn't working.

```
click element  ${SEARCH_BAR}
input text     ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${SEARCH_TERM}
click element  ${SEARCH_BUTTON}
click element  *locator*
```

I checked and the suggestion list stays on and doesn't disapear once something is typed and also tried pausing the test for a few second after typing the search term.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the elements you want to click (interact with).

Currently `${SEARCH_BAR}` is an empty variable so it cannot find an element.
For this you will need to chose a locator strategie for finding elements within DOM tree.

I mostly use xpath as locator strategie. That would mean your code would look like this:

```
${SEARCH_BAR}=   xpath=//*[contains(@text, 'search')]
click element    ${SEARCH_BAR}
input text       ${SEARCH_BAR}  ${SEARCH_TERM}='MySearchTerm'
click element    xpath=//*[contains(@class, 'submit')]
```

You will probably need to adapt these xpaths to be working in your environment.

First decide what locator strategie fits you.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/

Try to find one element at a time starting with `"search_bar"`. As soon as all elements are located correctly and all interactions are working as expected, you will probably also need to have a look at `Waits`.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/

If you are not familiar with webscraping, i suggest to first checkout the devtools of your browser and what they are capable of.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/